# Can i have kafka connect service as a standalone service

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using apache kafka in 1st server and apache zookeeper in 2nd server.
I want to have kafka connect service in other server.Is it possible to use a standalone service. I need to have apache kafka connect or confluent kafka connect

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "Confluent Kafka (Connect)"

Kafka Connect is Apache 2.0 Licensed and released as part of Apache Kafka. Confluent and other vendors write *plugins* (free, or enterprise-licensed) for Kafka Connect.

Yes, it it recommended to run Connect as a separate set of servers than either then brokers or zookeepers. In order to run it, you will need to download all of Kafka, then use `bin/connect-distributed`, or you can run it via Docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily run a Kafka Connect Standalone (Single Process) service from any server, provided you have configured both connector and workers properties correctly.

A gist of it here, if you are interested.

- In standalone mode all work is performed in a single process. It is easy to setup and get started but it does not benefit from some of the features of Kafka Connect such as fault tolerance.
- You can start a standalone process with the following command:

  **bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties connector1.properties connector2.properties**
- The first parameter is the configuration for the worker, it includes connection parameters, serialization format, and how frequently to commit offsets.

All workers (both standalone and distributed) require a few configs:

- **bootstrap.servers** - List of Kafka servers used to bootstrap connections to Kafka
- **Key/Value.converter** - Converter class used to convert between Kafka Connect format and the serialized form that is written to Kafka.
- **offset.storage.file.filename** - File to store offset data

### A Simple standalone connecter (Import Data from a file into KAFKA)

- kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 10 --topic connect-test to create a topic called connect-test with 10 partitions (Up to us) and replication factor of 2
- To start a standalone Kafka Connector, we need following three configuration files located under C:\kafka_2.11-1.1.0\config. Update these configuration files as following

**connect-standalone.properties**

offset.storage.file.filename=C:/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/connectConfig/connect.offsets

**connect-file-source.properties**

file=C:/kafka/Workspace/kafka.txt

**connect-file-sink.properties**

file=test.sink.txt

Execute the following command

```
Connect-standalone.bat  C:\kafka_2.11-1.1.0\config\connect-standalone.properties C:\kafka_2.11-1.1.0\config\connect-file-source.properties C:\kafka_2.11-1.1.0\config\connect-file-sink.properties
```

Once the Connector is started, initially the data in kafka.txt would be synced to test.sync.txt and the data is published to the Kafka Topic named, connect-test. Then any changes to the kafka.txt file would be synced to test.sync.txt and published to connect-test topic.

**Create a Consumer**

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9096 --topic connect-test --from-beginning
```

**CLI Output**

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9096 --topic connect-test --from-beginning
```

{"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"This is the stream data for the KAFKA Connector"}

Add a new line into “Consuming the events now” into the kafka.txt

**CLI Output**

kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9096 --topic connect-test --from-beginning

{"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"This is the stream data for the KAFKA Connector"}

{"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"Consuming the events now"}